# Bound for $\Vert\sum_iA_i^\dagger A_i\Vert_\infty$ given that $\Vert\sum_i A_i\Vert_\infty$ is small

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

Let $A_i$ be matrices such that

$$\left\Vert \sum_i A_i \right\Vert_\infty \leq \varepsilon,$$

where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$ is the operator norm and is equal to the largest singular value of its argument and $\dagger$ denotes the conjugate transpose. Can one say anything about an upper bound for

$$\left\Vert \sum_i A^\dagger_iA_i \right\Vert_\infty$$

in terms of $\varepsilon$? Moreover, is there a converse statement too i.e. given

$$\left\Vert \sum_i A^\dagger_iA_i \right\Vert_\infty\leq \delta$$

is there an upper bound for $\left\Vert \sum_i A_i \right\Vert_\infty$ in terms of $\delta$?

Comment: The converse look more promising. For the first statement, you run into trouble with situations like $A_i = (-1)^i A$ (for some constant matrix $A$)

Comment: By the way, does $A^\dagger$ refer to the conjugate-transpose of $A$? In some contexts, $A^\dagger$ denotes a pseudoinverse so this bears clarification

Comment: @BenGrossmann indeed, it's the conjugate transpose. Will edit the question to clarify. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that we have finitely many matrix $A_1,\dots,A_n$ to consider. Let $\tilde A$ denote the matrix
$$
\tilde A = \pmatrix{A_1\\ \vdots\\ A_n}.
$$
We see that $\sum_{i=1}^n A_i^\dagger A_i = \tilde A ^\dagger \tilde A$, so that
$$
\left\| \sum_{i=1}^n  A_iA_i^\dagger\right\|_{\infty}  
= \left\|\tilde A^\dagger \tilde A \right\|_\infty
= \left\| \tilde A\right\|_\infty^2 \leq \delta.
$$
On the other hand, we can write $\sum_{i=1}^n A_i$ as the product $M \tilde A$, where
$$
M = \pmatrix{I & \cdots & I}.
$$
We find that $\|M\|_\infty = \sqrt{n}$, so that
$$
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n A_i \right\|_\infty  = \| M \tilde A\|_\infty \leq \|M\|_\infty \cdot \|\tilde A\|_\infty  = \sqrt{n} \cdot \|\tilde A\|_\infty
\leq \sqrt{n\delta}.
$$